# Best way to optimize similar payload (React)

Tags: javascript, performance, react.js

I have to do some optimization on the function presented below.
It makes some data like a payload based on the arguments passed into it.

I am not much sure how to improve the code to look better & less.

Please share some thoughts on this.

```
//Process data and call track event for product added

export function ProductActionsSegment(data) {
    let cart_item = []
    data.session.cart.items.forEach(function (properties) {
            var items = {};
            items["brand"] = properties.product.display_brand;
            items["category"] = null;
            items["id"]= properties.id;
            items["imageUrl"]=properties.product.image.url;
            items["magento_product_id"]=properties.product.id;
            items["manufacturer"]=null;
            items["microcategory"]=null;
            items["name"]=properties.product.name;
            items["price"]=properties.product.price_range.minimum_price.final_price.value;
            items["product_id"]=properties.product.id;
            items["quantity"]=properties.quantity;
            items["regular_price"]=properties.product.price_range.minimum_price.regular_price.value;
            items["size"]=properties.product.size;
            items["size_type"]=properties.product.size_label;
            items["sku"]=properties.product.sku;
            items["special_category"]=null;
            items["special_price"]=properties.product.special_price;
            items["stock_quantity"]=null;
            items["swatch"]=properties.product.color_label;
            items["trend"]=null;
            items["url"]=properties.url;
            cart_item.push(items)
        });

    if(data.location == 'product_page' || data.location == 'product_list') {
        var product_page = {
            brand: data.product.brandName,
            category: null,
            country: null,
            email: Cookies.get('useremail'),
            imageUrl: null,
            location: data.location,
            magento_product_id: null,
            manufacturer: null,
            microcategory: null,
            name: data.product.name,
            price: data.product.price.price.value,
            product_id: null,
            products:cart_item,
            quantity: 1,
            regular_price: data.product.price.price.value,
            size: null,
            size_type: null,
            sku:data.product.sku,
            special_category: null,
            special_price: data.product.price.specialPrice,
            stock_quantity: null,
            swatch: null,
            trend: null,
            type: data.product.type,
            url: data.product.url
        };
        TrackEvent('Product Added',product_page);
        return;
    }
    if(data.location == 'cart') {
        var eventName;
        var type;
        if(!data.action && data.new_qty > data.product.quantity){
            eventName = 'Product Added';
            type = 'increseQuantity';
        }
        else if(data.action){
            eventName = 'Product Removed';
            type = 'xProduct';
        }
        else{
            eventName = 'Product Removed';
            type = 'decreaseQuantity';
        }
        var product_cart = {
            brand: null,
            category: null,
            country: null,
            email: Cookies.get('useremail'),
            imageUrl: null,
            location: data.location,
            magento_product_id: data.product.id,
            manufacturer: null,
            microcategory: null,
            name: data.product.name,
            price: data.product.price,
            product_id: data.product.id,
            products:cart_item,
            quantity: 1,
            regular_price: data.product.price,
            size: data.product.product.size,
            size_type: null,
            sku:data.product.product.sku,
            special_category: null,
            special_price: data.product.product.special_price,
            stock_quantity: null,
            swatch: data.product.product.color_label,
            trend: null,
            type: type,
            url: data.product.url
        };

        return product_cart
    }
}
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. Helpful. reviews. take. time: expect answers to simple&short code within a couple of hours rather than minutes. While waiting for reviews, (re)visit [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve the title of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue with this function is that it's very difficult to follow what the function is doing with the giant object-creation stuff in the middle of the function. I would extract each of those large chunks into separate helper functions so that it's easy to see at a glance the general idea of what `ProductActionsSegment()` does.

Here's an untested example (that also includes a few other minor cleanups):

```javascript
export function ProductActionsSegment(data) {
  const cartItem = data.session.cart.items.map(formatCartItem);
  switch (data.location) {
    case 'product_page':
    case 'product_list':
      TrackEvent('Product Added', formatProductPage({ data, cartItem }));
      return;

    case 'cart':
      const type = extractCartTypeFromData(data);
      return formatCartPage({ data, cartItem, type });
  }
}

function extractCartTypeFromData(data) {
  if (data.action) {
    return 'xProduct';
  } else {
    return data.new_qty > data.product.quantity
      ? 'increseQuantity'
      : 'decreaseQuantity';
  }
}

const formatCartItem = ({ id, quantity, url, product }) => ({
  id,
  quantity,
  url,
  brand: product.display_brand,
  category: null,
  imageUrl: product.image.url,
  magento_product_id: product.id,
  manufacturer: null,
  microcategory: null,
  name: product.name,
  price: product.price_range.minimum_price.final_price.value,
  product_id: product.id,
  regular_price: product.price_range.minimum_price.regular_price.value,
  size: product.size,
  size_type: product.size_label,
  sku: product.sku,
  special_category: null,
  special_price: product.special_price,
  stock_quantity: null,
  swatch: product.color_label,
  trend: null,
});

const formatProductPage = ({ data: { product, location }, cartItem }) => ({
  brand: product.brandName,
  category: null,
  country: null,
  email: Cookies.get('useremail'),
  imageUrl: null,
  location,
  magento_product_id: null,
  manufacturer: null,
  microcategory: null,
  name: product.name,
  price: product.price.price.value,
  product_id: null,
  products: cartItem,
  quantity: 1,
  regular_price: product.price.price.value,
  size: null,
  size_type: null,
  sku: product.sku,
  special_category: null,
  special_price: product.price.specialPrice,
  stock_quantity: null,
  swatch: null,
  trend: null,
  type: product.type,
  url: product.url,
});

const formatCartPage = ({ data: { product, location }, cartItem, type }) => ({
  brand: null,
  category: null,
  country: null,
  email: Cookies.get('useremail'),
  imageUrl: null,
  location,
  magento_product_id: product.id,
  manufacturer: null,
  microcategory: null,
  name: product.name,
  price: product.price,
  product_id: product.id,
  products: cartItem,
  quantity: 1,
  regular_price: product.price,
  size: product.product.size,
  size_type: null,
  sku: product.product.sku,
  special_category: null,
  special_price: product.product.special_price,
  stock_quantity: null,
  swatch: product.product.color_label,
  trend: null,
  type,
  url: product.url,
});
```

A few other things:

- Your original version has an unused eventName variable.
- Are objects of these shapes being created in multiple locations? If not, ignore the following advice. If so, you might want a general helpers such as `createCartPage({ brand: ..., , category: ..., etc })`. This would make it so you don't have to explicitly set "null" to a bunch of different attributes as the helper can take care of that for you. Example helper:

```
const createBlankCartPage = (attrs = {}) => Object.assign(Object.seal({
  brand: null,
  category: 'some-default-category',
  country: null,
  email: null,
  // ...
}), attrs);
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer.